# Stripe checkout: description in dashboard instead of pi

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Can anyone help me? I migrate form v2 to v3 checkout.

how can I send my custom description order in stripe dashboard description column?
now I get only the payment id `pi_1IrhQALKfdoxxl3X07seJ5anto`

with old API by description I would do:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $_POST['amount'],
    "currency" => "EUR",
    "description" => "Order #".$_POST["order"],
    "source" => $token,
));
```

with the new API :

```
    $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
  'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'price' => 'price_H5ggYwtDq4fbrJ',
      'quantity' => 2,
    ],
  ],
  'mode' => 'payment',
]);
```

Thank you

Comment: I hope you have fully sanitised that `$_POST` data before putting it anywhere near your Stripe code......

Comment: @Martin you talkin about variables? special chars? let me know, very tnaks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to the stripe documentation : https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-description

```
$stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
  'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'price' => 'price_H5ggYwtDq4fbrJ',
      'quantity' => 2,
    ],
  ],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'payment_intent_data' => [
    'description' => "Order #".$_POST["order"]
  ]
]);
```